# Klarna Api - Email address not in response

Tags: api, payment, klarna

I'm trying to integrate the klarna api:
https://developers.klarna.com/en/us/kco-v3/checkout/javascript-api

Unfortunately when I do:

```
window._klarnaCheckout(function(api) {
  api.on({
    'change': function(data) {
     console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

This only returns the zip and postal_code but not the entered email address or other information like the name.

Is this a klarna issue or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Only once the form within the Klarna iframe is submitted, the event is triggered, and information is returned. Unfortunately, I have only managed to get it to return **email, postal_code, country, given_name and family_name**. Address doesn't seem to want to play.

Hope this helps (at least a little).